# Google wallet,Merchant account and sandbox

Tags: android, android-pay, merchant-account

Request the Full Wallet:

```
    FullWalletRequest fullWalletRequest = FullWalletRequest.newBuilder()
  .setGoogleTransactionId(googleTransactionId)
  .setCart(Cart.newBuilder()
          .setCurrencyCode(Constants.CURRENCY_CODE_USD)
          .setTotalPrice(toDollars(context, itemInfo.getTotalPrice()))
          .addLineItem(LineItem.newBuilder()
                  .setCurrencyCode(Constants.CURRENCY_CODE_USD)
                  .setDescription(itemInfo.name)
                  .setQuantity("1")
                  .setUnitPrice(toDollars(context, itemInfo.priceMicros))
                  .setTotalPrice(toDollars(context, itemInfo.priceMicros))
                  .build())
          .addLineItem(LineItem.newBuilder()
                  .setCurrencyCode(Constants.CURRENCY_CODE_USD)
                  .setDescription(Constants.DESCRIPTION_LINE_ITEM_SHIPPING)
                  .setRole(LineItem.Role.SHIPPING)
                  .setTotalPrice(toDollars(context, itemInfo.shippingPriceMicros))
                  .build())
          .addLineItem(LineItem.newBuilder()
                  .setCurrencyCode(Constants.CURRENCY_CODE_USD)
                  .setDescription(Constants.DESCRIPTION_LINE_ITEM_TAX)
                  .setRole(LineItem.Role.TAX)
                  .setTotalPrice(toDollars(context, itemInfo.taxMicros))
                  .build())
          .build())
  .build();
```

Notify Google Wallet of your Transaction Processing:

```
    Wallet.Payments.notifyTransactionStatus(mGoogleApiClient,
  WalletUtil.createNotifyTransactionStatusRequest(fullWallet.getGoogleTransactionId(),
                NotifyTransactionStatusRequest.Status.SUCCESS));
```

Now it show the transaction is successful. But now i have following questions.

1. How to transfer amount from google wallet to merchant account ?
2. Any way to transfer amount between google wallet to merchant account?
3. Is there any sandbox available for google wallet merchant account?
4. How to integrate merchant account with the app? Is there any code?

   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1.2. To transfer amount to merchant account you need any payment processor. Google wallet support payment processors like Stripe, Braintree, VANTIV, First Data, CyberSource.

3. You can do SEND BOX testing using Stripe or Braintree, etc...
4. We can not create merchant account in application. We have to crate merchant account using any of the Payment Processor sites.

Also with google wallet you have to generate CLIENT ID for your project.

Comment: I used Braintree and now Android pay support is there ,We have to
1-Generate client token from our server
2-Add Masked Wallet request with braintree tokenization parameter.
3-Generate payment method nonce.(Charge token)
4-Send it to server to charge card.
5-Get response and you have done.

Answer (score 0):

The full wallet request would have to be sent via a call to `loadFullWallet(...)` which would then result in a call to `onActivityResult()` containing an extra that contains the FullWallet object.

The FullWallet object contains a proxy card (akin to a credit card). You can use any backend processor like braintree/stripe to process the payment using the proxy card. Once this is processed, the money would be transferred to the merchant account based on the backend processor.